# Using azure to upload data to the corporate database

Tags: azure, cloud

At the moment I am working as a .NET developer on a project for one of my clients. The first phase of this project is to build a desktop WPF application that can read and store csv files to a local sql compact database. With this data the user can create plots and do some calculation with it. So far so good. Finally we want to upload this data to a SQL database that is localized inside the corporate network. The idea is to use some kind of cloud service where the WPF application can connect to and deploy a windows service within the corporate network to get this data from the cloud to the local database. User using the WPF application will only have access to connect to the cloud service and not to the corporate network.

I am totally new to cloud and I was wondering if anybody has experience with this kind of setup and give me some advice. For example, what kind of cloud service / solution should be used here.

Answer (score 0):

As individual users will have csv files locally and your requirement is to store and sync data through cloud, I could suggest a simple solution as below:

Create a very simple ASP.NET cloud Service and add an interface where individual users can upload their CSV to Azure and in your cloud service app you can move that CSV file to Azure Storage to persist. (you can also create a web service front end which individual users can access directly from WPF app to upload CSV but lot more code needed). If you add code to upload csv from WPF app to Azure Storage you may need Storage Key locally which is not good otherwise you could use SAS (Shared Access Signature) to provide time based access. You can keep the csv on Cloud Service VM but it will not persist and that't why you would need to use Azure Storage.

Once CSV file is uploaded to Azure Storage, you can sync it to on-premise SQL Database by enabling proper firewall setting.

In the cloud service, you can add more code to read the CSV from Azure Blob Storage and write directly to Azure Cloud SQL Database and there is no need to have on-premise SQL Server at all which is the best option.